# Error Android No matching client found for package name 'company.nombrepaquete.nombrepaquete'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle, build.gradle

Hola resulta que no tengo ningún error de compilación en mi android studio, pero al intentar correr el app, sale este error de Gradle:

> No matching client found for package name
>   'company.nombrepaquete.nombrepaquete'

Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

Comment: Puede dar mas detalles, para poder ayudarte? esta trabajando con `Google Analytics` etc, proporcione mas detalles.

Comment: J.Rodriguez, gracias por la ayuda, ya tenemos respuesta correcta

Answer (score 18, accepted):

El problema sucede porque el archivo `google-services.json` contiene una definición de paquete diferente a la de tu proyecto.

**El "package_name" definido dentro del archivo `google-services.json` debe ser el de la aplicación.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Super!! Gracias